# Spreading a push notification batch over a time period

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to spread the sending of push notification messages over a time period using Parse (or any service of this king).

Here is the use case : we want to send daily messages to a large user base, and as we don't want these messages to generate a burst of connections our infrastructure could have difficulties to handle.

For this reason we need to be able to specify the "duration" of the push while sending a message.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a Parse.com point of view you can construct your push target query in a way that it only selects a subset of recipient using `skip` and `limit`. Then simply divide your audience into batches of X recipients and schedule these pushes to be sent out at a specific time.

You can also send out the pushes to everyone "at once" but set it to be delivered in the users' time zone. So a user in Europe will receive the notification at 10am in his local time zone, which translates to 2am PST, the user in the PST timezone won't receive the notification until 8h later so it is spread out as well.

Comment: We've though about these kind of solutions (tagging cohorts of users), but it seems a lot of work for getting something that limits a lot the point of using Parse.